# When should a bixby developer use SearchTerm vs SearchRegion?

Tags: bixby

I am interested in adding a search for a city but I am not 100% sure what part of the geo capsule to use. It sort of seems like SearchTerm is for distinct points like a specific address(at least that is what NamedPoint seems to be) and SearchRegion seems to be more like a region or city.

The SearchTerm section mentions a city, Mountain View (which i *think* is not a single point in space, but a two dimensional range. it could be the center point of Mountain view maybe?)

> Utterances such as "SFO", "60 South Market Street", "Mountain View"
>   and "Golden Gate Bridge" can all be trained with SearchTerm. Your capsule does not have to handle the search action, but instead just needs one or more action that takes a NamedPoint as an input.

Adding to my confusion, I might not understand the difference between concepts you train on and inputs. the SearchRegion section says that's the one to use if you train on named points:

> If you have trained on named points or divisions, you should provide
>   actions that take SearchRegion concepts as inputs.

I thought that training was done on inputs, but is there a difference between "training on a named point" and "NamedPoint input"? NamedPoint inputs seemed to go with the SearchTerm while named point trainings go with SearchRegions.

Does anyone have an understanding on when to use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Both `SearchRegion` and `SearchTerm` can help you search for a city.

As mentioned in the docs, you want to use `SearchRegion` when you expect your users to use `LocalityName` or `NeighborhoodName` etc.

You may want to refer to [this](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.geo) for more clarity on what each of the divisions mean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That documentation link you posted in your last sentence is what I am hoping to get clarification on. Is SearchTerm just for NamedPoints and SearchRegion for anything in that list at [https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.geo#using-searchregion]?

Comment: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.geo#using-searchterm

Specifically read through the section that talks about Using Search Region,  `For instance, if you've trained on NeighborhoodName, searching on "mission district" when the user is in San Francisco will find San Francisco's Mission District, but not if the user is in San Jose. If you've trained on a concept that corresponds to a specific point such a StreetAddress or a PlaceName, the search radius is applied after the location is found.`